# CSS file not linking to HTML file when website uploaded online

Tags: html, css

I have tested out my website from my computer without any web hosting and my html document and css document are linking perfectly. However, when i decided to try it out online on 000webhost, i uploaded both files and made sure that the directories were correct, but the html document ended up with no style whatsoever. Can someone please help me, I'm new with this stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>BandRate</title>
    </head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="title">
        <div id="title">
            <span class="capital_letter">B</span>and<span class="capital_letter">R</span>ate
        </div>
        <a href="test.html" id="SignUp">Band Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.page {
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
.title {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%; 
    height:75px; 
    background-color:#800000;
}
#title {
    font-family:broadway;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#FF0000;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:0px;
}
#SignUp {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#690404;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-family:broadway;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ff0000;
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#SignUp:hover {
    background-color:#540303;
}   
.capital_letter {
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Install Firefox FireBug plugin and check what's happening at the HTTP tab. Most likely you will see 404.

Comment: does the index.html and css file are in same directory?

Comment: Did you copy the CSS file to the same folder as your HTML? And Ondra is correct that you should use Firebug or a similar tool to determine whether the CSS has actually loaded.

Comment: Could you post a link to the problem site?

Comment: I had a pretty similar issue with Safari and my website at 000webhost however it was not "updating" my CSS when I was uploading changes I had made locally, I just had to delete my website data for my website at http://dummycode.com and the issue was fixed.

Comment: If your OS is linux there should be some permission issue.

Comment: can you share the link?

Answer (score 1):

check to see if your html file is in the same directory where the css file is.

if not then instead of linking your css file like this -

> "stylesheet.css"

Link it like this -

> "name_of_directory/stylesheet.css"

if your css file is in a directory and your html file is in other directory then link your css like this -

> "../name_of_directory/stylesheet.css"

you could also link your css file like this:

> "http://your_website.com/name_of_directory/stylesheet.css"

Answer (score 0):

A few items to check:
1. Check that you actually uploaded the CSS. If you did, and the permissions are correct, is it named stylesheet.css, all lowercase? If it's on a non-Windows system it may care about casing.
2. Is the CSS in the same folder as the HTML?
3. Give us more information and we can help, such as the hosting type, whether the HTML file is in a subfolder, and so forth. If it's in a subfolder, your path to the CSS file is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.

My File on my computer was named "background.JPG" and I had linked it in my CSS dokument with "Background-image: Url(background.jpg)" which worked completely fine on my computer but not on 000webhosting.

As it turns out, I had to go into my file in 000webhosting "fileview" where I changed the link to "Background-image: Url(background.JPG)"

Yes... It can be that simple...

000webhosting is Case sensitive when you link things.

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I came across the problem today and I found the solution. The reason is that the path in your `html` file cannot be recognized by the online server.

For example, I use the Linux apache2 tool to host my website. The default website folder is **/var/www/html/**

Let's say you stored subpages in **/var/www/html/error-404/404.html** & **/var/www/html/error-404/style.css**. Obviously, the `css` file and `html` file is in the same folder. You probably wrote the path as **href="sytle.css**". However, the server would not find the `css` path.

The correct path is **href="/error-404/css/style.css"**. The path should start from the document root of your website (im my case: the root path is **/var/www/html**).

Answer (score -1):

try to change

```
href="stylesheet.css"
```

into

```
href=//Put the full path to css file
```

Comment: at least he can figure out what is wrong,if it's because of that,then he can put a relative path