# Live site does not match local site

Tags: html, css

I recently added an email form to my site. Everything worked find for Safari, chrome and IE 10. After uploading my files onto the server the live site has missing styles. The site should look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3ueJyncJ7eTGY3OHVtQmR3bUE/view?usp=sharing but instead it looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3ueJyncJ7eeThZcEhzMWpPMnM/view?usp=sharing

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CloudHudl</title>
<link href="Landing_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>                                                          
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <header>
          <div id= "logo"></div>
    </header>

    <div class="Organge">
    <div id= "UltimateGame">
    ULTIMATE GAME DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM
    </div>
    <div id= "CloudHudlis">
    CloudHudl is a platform for developers, artist and producers.
    </div>
    <div id= "ConnectandForm">
    Connect and Form Develpment Teams
    </div>
    <div id= "CreateandDevelop">
    Create and Develop Games Through the Web
    </div>
    <div id="WePublish">
    We Publish Your Games!
    </div>
    </div>
<div id= "StayInformed">
      STAY INFORMED
    </div>
    <div id="About">
        We are creating a platform for developers, artist, and producers from all walks of life. Our platform gives people with an idea the ability to connect with talented individuals from
        across the globe. Project management, file sharing and collaboration, and development are simple to run on CloudHudl. In addition, our publishing services for games gives producers’ 
        complete creative freedom, so they can create the content they want to create. Our platform allows talented producers and designers to create unhindered projects of any size, from 
        anywhere in the world and provides the opportunity for any project to succeed, not just exist. If you’re a developer, producer, artist, coder, or just interested in getting involved, 
        fill out our form below to stay up to date and receive a notification before our launch date.
     </div>
<div class= "Grey">
    </div>
    <div id= "bubble">
    </div>
    <div id= "sheet">
    </div>
    <div id= "controller">
    </div>       
    <!-- Sign-up -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//cloudhudl.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=e31b06ffc35cb8b0ebaa0081b&amp;id=79f3fa778c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--end signup--> 
    <footer>
      <address>
        Copyright 2015 &#169;
        (620) 605-2154;
      </address>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>


/* 
  Cloud Hudl
  Index stylesheet

  Author: Cameron Hall
  Date: 9/25/2015
  Filename: indexstyles.cc
*/

html, body { height: 100%; }

.Organge {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fa7862;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
.Grey {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    clear: both;
}
#UltimateGame
{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    top: 22%;
    width: 479px;
    height: 26px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
#CloudHudlis
{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 38.5%;
  top: 26%;
  width: 377px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 4;
 }
 #ConnectandForm
{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 26px;
  z-index: 5;
}
#CreateandDevelop
{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 132px;
  height: 26px;
  z-index: 9;
}
#WePublish
{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 76%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 135px;
  height: 9px;
  z-index: 6;
}
#StayInformed
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 42.83%;
    top: 80%;
    width: 197px;
    height: 128px;
    z-index: 18;
}

#mce-EMAIL
{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
input.button
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    background-color: #fa7862;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 120%;
}
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease; 
  opacity: 0;
}
#mc_embed_signup
{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  top: 85%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 3.5%;
  z-index: 13;
}
#logo
{
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 36.5%;
  top: 4%;
  width: 425px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 7;  
}
#bubble
{
  background-image: url("bubble.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.57%;
  top: 37.8%;
  width: 72px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 8;
}
#sheet
{
  background-image: url("sheet.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 47%;
  top: 37.8%;
  width: 56px;
  height: 72px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#controller
{
  background-image: url("controller.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 77%;
  top: 38.55%;
  width: 92px;
  height: 59px;
  z-index: 11;
}
#About {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

footer {
clear: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

footer address {
width: 100%;
clear: left;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: small-caps;
background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
```

Comment: Tried clearing browser cache? Also, try to see the `CSS URL` content using debugger tools on browser.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache but that doesn't change anything. Also tried it on other computers. The css isn't missing. If it wasn't linked wouldn't all of the styles be missing?

Comment: it might help: [CSS file not linking to HTML file when website uploaded online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508417/css-file-not-linking-to-html-file-when-website-uploaded-online)

Comment: So it does in fact fail to load the mailchimp link... I don't know why though

Comment: I added the link to the mailchimp css. The developer console no longer registers an error but it still displays wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be having a caching issue. To test, visit http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css... if it doesnt show you the CSS you are expecting (a stale, older version) then thats your problem.

Your css file being served by Mailchimp's CDN probably needs to be invalidated

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are saying... it doesn't return anything related to my css. The css my site returns matches what I have, it just doesn't display properly.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT! So I had linked to the mailchimp css in the header. I actually had to REMOVE the link fix the problem. First I tried moving the link into my body just to see if it worked but obviously it didn't. As usually, it was an obvious mistake but just had to remove the link to the Mailchimp css. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Things that aren't the same are not the same:

```
diff -s <(curl -s http://localsite/) <(curl -s http://livesite/)
```